# Groovy split without final trim

Tags: groovy

I'm parsing a CVS file like the following:

```
"07555555555",25.70,18/11/2010,01/03/2011,N,133,0,36,,896,537,547,,Mr,John,Doe,,
"07555555555",10.15,26/01/2011,01/03/2011,N,16,0,100,,896,537,547,,Mrs,Jane,Doe,,jane@doe.com
```

The thing is that when using a script like this:

```
file.eachLine{ line ->

    items = line.split(",")
    println items.length
}
```

The result is like the following:

```
16
18
```

Which makes me thing that the **split** function removes a final values. I need it to have all the items even if they are empty. Any idea?

Comment: It might be worth your while to use a library instead of recreating the parsing logic for csv yourself. I'd suggest using opencsv or groovycsv https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv/, a groovy wrapper for opencsv (disclaimer: I'm the author of groovycsv). You can read more about parsing csv in groovy here: http://www.kellyrob99.com/blog/2010/07/01/groovy-and-csv-how-to-get-your-data-out/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to do:

```
items = line.split(',', -1)
```

to make sure you get all the tokens

(according to [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)):

> The limit parameter controls the
>   number of times the pattern is applied
>   and therefore affects the length of
>   the resulting array. If the limit n is
>   greater than zero then the pattern
>   will be applied at most n - 1 times,
>   the array's length will be no greater
>   than n, and the array's last entry
>   will contain all input beyond the last
>   matched delimiter. **If n is
>   non-positive then the pattern will be
>   applied as many times as possible and
>   the array can have any length**. If n is
>   zero then the pattern will be applied
>   as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and trailing
>   empty strings will be discarded.